# Why does the standard kaddish formula refer to consolations?

Tags: kaddish

In listing the praises of God in the standard text of [kaddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish) it states:

> Blessed and praised, glorified and exalted,extolled and honoured, adored and lauded   be the name of the Holy One, blessed be He, above and beyond all the blessings, hymns, praises and **consolations** that are uttered in the world

the word consolations - וְנֶחֱמָתָא is included. This seems to me to be an unusual form of praise. Is there any documented explanation for how/why this term was included in kaddish?